# Too many fields which were annotated by @value need to be defined in a bean scope while using spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations, spring-el

When I was using spring MVC, its annotation features is very difference between XML way. It seems can be more convenient and efficient. 
BUT, 
HOW TO INJECT a number of properties into a number of bean made me feel confused.

As all we know, in XML way, it was very clear as below.

```
${"xxx.xxx.key:default"}
```

also, the spel is equivalent to `@Value`.

but, with `@Value`, there are too many global field need to be defined in a bean.
So, how to avoid it? or a better practice? I have tried `PropertyOverrideConfigurer`, but beanname.field is not a better choice for me?

Comment: If you have 10 xml values you also need 10 `@Value` those should translate 1-on-1... I don't really see the difference...

Comment: yeah, image that if there are over 100 values need to be injected, how UGLY the code will be.

Comment: Then your XML would be as ugly, only difference it would be externalized.

Comment: Create property beans which contain multiple numbers of properties and inject those property beans to your services

Comment: Which is also the approach that spring Boot takes (I suggest a look on that).

Comment: @M.Deinum No, I don't think the XML way would be ugly, as we don't really need to declare fields which were already declared in your bean.

Comment: @AliDehghani yes, create property bean could solved this issues, but I don't think it was a better practice for me because it had a strong association with the bean id(name)